# Window Manager to Close Windows to the System Tray

Tags: windows, window-manager

I'm looking for software that will override the close button for certain desktop windows to where instead of closing the window and exiting the application, it sends the window to the taskbar. I'm looking for the same functionality as [RBTray](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/) but instead of right-clicking the minimize button, I can instead click the exit button.

The software should provide some type of option to choose a specific executables or look for specific a window title in order to differentiate which windows it should minimize to the taskbar and windows that should close normally.

This software must be compatible with Windows 10. Gratis is preferred but paid software is also accepted.